# -bash: iTMSTransporter: command not found

Tags: ios, xml, command-line

I have install  iTMSTransporter and try to run it from it is destination directory  in order to fetch the metadata from iTunes Connect .
I am in lookup mode and used following command:
iTMSTransporter -m lookupMetadata -u uid -p password -vendor_id SnapLion000011 - destination /Users/Snaplion4/Desktop

and got following error :
-bash: iTMSTransporter: command not found

Answer (score 2):

On my Mac the installer installed the binaries here. /usr/local/itms/bin
I cd into that folder and run 
$ ./iTMSTransporter -m verify -f .....

Answer (score 1):

You might not be in the same folder with iTMSTransporter. If you are in the same folder try adding ./ at the beginning of the command.

BTW you should hide your password. I can't believe superwoman has that much downloads.